# Issue deploying EAR project from eclipse to EAP 6.2.0 using JBoss Tools Plugin

Tags: eclipse, ear, jboss-tools

I have a maven EAR project, which contains a couple of WAR and JAR files. I'm using Spring STS IDE with JBoss Tools 1.6.0 (latest).
       When I try to deploy my EAR to JBoss EAP 6.2.0 with JBoss Tools from STS  i'm facing the following issues.
My Jars (external jars and project jar) are getting copied into WEB-INF/lib and EAR/lib, where i expected it to be only in EAR/lib.
EAR application.xml is not getting copied into EAR/META-INF/ folder
     But when i use terminal to build my project and deploy EAR, i'm not experiencing these issue and JBoss starts without any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's its solved [JBIDE-19047](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-19047) The main issues are,

1. jars are getting copied into WEB-INF/lib due to skinnywar not supported by eclipse m2e-wtp plugin and this can be solved by adding `<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>` in war plugin configuration.
2. application.xml not getting copied into ear/META-INF/ folder, if you have any unresolved dependency in any of the pom then this would occur, so make sure all jar dependencies are available.